# Getting error when I'm going to mint NFT on testnet using Metaplex

Tags: spl-token, metaplex, anchor-lang, metaplex-js, anchor-client

Here is my mint contract

```
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;
use anchor_lang::solana_program::program::invoke;
use anchor_spl::token::mint_to;
use anchor_spl::token::{MintTo, Token};
use mpl_token_metadata::instruction::create_metadata_accounts_v2;

declare_id!("2wNRvHNzYFivSBaG344SR4GqXAHVVjjxb7GLWzw3YHoA");

#[program]
pub mod sol_mint_nft {
    use super::*;

    pub fn mint_nft(
        ctx: Context<MintNFT>,
        creator_key: Pubkey,
        name: String,
        symbol: String,
        uri: String,
    ) -> Result<()> {
        msg!("Nft token minting:");
        let cpi_program = ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info();
        let cpi_accounts = MintTo {
            mint: ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info(),
            to: ctx.accounts.token_account.to_account_info(),
            authority: ctx.accounts.payer.to_account_info(),
        };
        let cpi_ctx = CpiContext::new(cpi_program, cpi_accounts);
        let result = mint_to(cpi_ctx, 1);
        if let Err(_) = result {
            return Err(error!(ErrorCode::MintFailed));
        }
        msg!("Token minted !!!");

        msg!("Metadata account creating:");
        let accounts = vec![
            ctx.accounts.token_metadata_program.to_account_info(),
            ctx.accounts.metadata.to_account_info(),
            ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info(),
            ctx.accounts.mint_authority.to_account_info(),
            ctx.accounts.payer.to_account_info(),
            ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
            ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
            ctx.accounts.rent.to_account_info(),
        ];
        let creators = vec![
            mpl_token_metadata::state::Creator {
                address: creator_key,
                verified: true,
                share: 100,
            },
            mpl_token_metadata::state::Creator {
                address: ctx.accounts.mint_authority.key(),
                verified: true,
                share: 0,
            },
        ];
        let result = invoke(
            &create_metadata_accounts_v2(
                ctx.accounts.token_metadata_program.key(),
                ctx.accounts.metadata.key(),
                ctx.accounts.mint.key(),
                ctx.accounts.mint_authority.key(),
                ctx.accounts.payer.key(),
                ctx.accounts.payer.key(),
                name,
                symbol,
                uri,
                Some(creators),
                1,
                true,
                false,
                None,
                None,
            ),
            &accounts,
        );
        if let Err(_) = result {
            return Err(error!(ErrorCode::MetadataCreateFailed));
        }
        msg!("Metadata account created !!!");
        Ok(())
    }
}
```

Contract deployed on testnet.([https://api.testnet.solana.com](https://api.testnet.solana.com://))

Error Logs:

[image]

Comment: You need to show what accounts are in your context, and you are providing from the test script. Before trying it on devnet, I'd start a local validator that also deploys metaplex program. If you can get it running there, you'll save on devnet SOL and testing will be much faster. Only when it works perfectly would I try it on devnet.

Answer (score 0):

These are the accounts the `CreateMetadataAccountV2` instruction is expecting, you're missing the system program account.

```
    #[account(0, writable, name="metadata", desc="Metadata key (pda of ['metadata', program id, mint id])")]
    #[account(1, name="mint", desc="Mint of token asset")]
    #[account(2, signer, name="mint_authority", desc="Mint authority")]
    #[account(3, signer, writable, name="payer", desc="payer")]
    #[account(4, name="update_authority", desc="update authority info")]
    #[account(5, name="system_program", desc="System program")]
    #[account(6, optional, name="rent", desc="Rent info")]
    CreateMetadataAccountV2(CreateMetadataAccountArgsV2),
```

Also, FYI, since mpl-token-metadata version 1.3.0 the `MetadataInstruction::CreateMetadataAccountV3` instruction is recommended.

Comment: Not working! getting the new error "Program log: Error: BorshIoError"